# Combining two samples out of numpy.random does not end up in a random sequence

Tags: python, random

I implemented the [Wald-Wolfowitz runs test](https://github.com/warreee/wald-wolfowitz-runs-test) but during testing I encountered weird behaviour, the steps I take are the following:

1. I take two samples out of the same distribution:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   list_dist_A = np.random.chisquare(2, 1000)
   list_dist_B = np.random.chisquare(2, 1000)
   ```
2. I concatenate the two lists and sort them, while remembering which number came from which sample. The following function does that and it returns a list of labels ["A","B","A","A", ... "B"]

   ```
   def _get_runs_list(list1, list2):
        # Add labels  
        l1 = list(map(lambda x: (x, "A"), list1))
        l2 = list(map(lambda x: (x, "B"), list2))
        # Concatenate
        lst = l1 + l2
        # Sort
        sorted_list = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
        # Return only the labels:
        return [l[1] for l in sorted_list]
   ```
3. Now I want to calculate the number of runs (a consecutive sequence of identical labels). e.g.:

   - a,b,a,b has 4 runs
   - a,a,a,b,b has 2 runs
   - a,b,b,b,a,a has 3 runs

   For this I use the following code:

   ```
   def _calculate_nruns(labels):
       nruns = 0
       last_seen = None

       for label in labels:
           if label != last_seen:
               nruns += 1
           last_seen = label

       return nruns
   ```

Since all elements are randomly drawn I thought that I should roughly end up with a sequence `a,b,a,b,a,b...` So this would mean that the number of runs is roughly 2000. 
However as can be seen [in this snippet on "repl.it"](https://repl.it/H2uZ/0) this is not the case, it is always roughly around 1000.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: This is a great question! Hopefully, a statistician reads this. I don't think it's an artifact of your code.

Comment: Your intution that you should end up with a sequence that is roughly `a, b, a, b, a, b` is likely not right. But this is better suited for a probability/math/stats audience

Comment: As a matter of fact I did ask this first on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276025/taking-two-sets-a-b-out-of-the-same-distribution-merging-and-then-sorting-sh). But no luck there yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

~1000 is the expected result. [Following the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) on this statistical test, you have `Np = Nn = 1000` and `N = Np + Nn = 2000`. That means that the expected value for the number of runs is `mu = 2 * Np * Nn / N + 1` which is 1001.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, that reminds me of the [Gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

I'm not a statistician but to get 2000 runs you would need a 100% chance that `A` follows `B` and `B` follows `A`. This would indicate that the PRNG has some sort of memory of previous draws. That wouldn't be good...

OTOH, assume you have drawn a value labelled `A`, then there's a 50% chance to draw another `A` and a 50% chance to draw a `B`. So the chance to draw a length-one-run is actually only 50%, the chance to get a length-two run is 25%, for length-three it's 12.5%, for length-four it's 6.25 and so on.

The last part can easily be verified:

```
import numpy as np
list_dist_A = np.random.chisquare(2, 1000)
list_dist_B = np.random.chisquare(2, 1000)

listA = [(value, 'A') for value in list_dist_A]
listB = [(value, 'B') for value in list_dist_B]
combined = sorted(listA+listB, key=lambda x: x[0])
combined = [x[1] for x in combined]

from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

runlengths = [len(list(it)) for _, it in groupby(combined)]  # lengths of the individual runs
print(Counter(runlengths))  # similar to a histogram
# Counter({1: 497, 2: 234, 3: 131, 4: 65, 5: 29, 6: 20, 7: 11, 8: 2, 10: 1, 14: 1})
```

So this is actually quite close to the expectation (which would be: `1: 500, 2: 250, 3: 125, 4:62, ...` as mentioned above). If your assumption would be correct it would be more close to `1:2000, 2: 0, ...`